# OpenAI API: Can I access my custom ChatGPT via API?

Tags: openai-api

I have built my own GPT using ChatGPT, and the same has been made public on some URL. I am unable to find a way to make API calls to my own GPT that is created through ChatGPT. Is such functionality available?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about accessing [custom ChatGPTs](https://openai.com/blog/introducing-gpts) that were recently introduced with the [GPT Store](https://openai.com/blog/introducing-the-gpt-store), then the answer is no. **It's not possible to access a custom ChatGPT via the OpenAI API.**

However, you can create your assistant and access it via the [Assistants API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/overview/agents).